# How to redirect syslog logs using C/UNIX?

Tags: c, unix, logging, posix

When I run this program,

```
#include <syslog.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    syslog(LOG_ERR, "testing 1..2..3");

    return 0;
}
```

The log message gets outputted to the `/var/log/system.log`. What I would like to do is redirect this message to different file of my choosing. How can I do this via C/POSIX API ? Thanks for any help.

Comment: that'd be have to be done at the syslog configuration level. the syslog() function sends it to the specific log facility.

Comment: @MarcB Do you mean that I can't modify this programmatically ?

Comment: It would be a bad idea if a user can redirect the syslogs at her will. If you want to output something elsewhere, don't use the `syslog` facility. I smell the haut-gout of an XY-problem.

Comment: Your program chooses the facility and logging level. The `syslog` configuration file then specifies the disposition of each facility and level.

Comment: @P.P. Presumably to take advantage of other features, like log message formatting and the ability to rotate the log files without modifying the applications.

Comment: syslog()'s first arg is basically just a number to tell the syslog daemon which log "facility" to write to. there's no provision to provide that number, OR a filename. all you can do is say "write to log #7" or "write to log #92", not "write to /some/random/file". if you want to write to a specific file, you have to configure a particular log facility to use that file, and that's done in the syslog daemon configuration.

Comment: @MarcB So this basically, if I want a particular file to have the output, I have to go manually edit the syslog.conf file ? NOTHING, can be done programmatically ? I should mention that this is a HW assignment so nothing serious is happening.

Comment: sure, you can do it programmatically, just not using the syslog() function. nothing to stop you from doing an fopen/fwrite/fclose() to any file you want.

Comment: You can try the [log4c library](http://log4c.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Specify the exact wording of the HW assignment.